# Select a record with a value if exists, otherwise a second value, otherwise a third one. (hierarchically)

Tags: sql, select

I have a table (tbl_payments) with 4 columns like this:

```
+------------+------------+-------+------------+  
| User_id    | Name       | Status|  Payment No|
+------------+------------+-------+------------+
```

Now imagine records like this.

```
1| Luigi | Active | 1
1| Luigi | Active | 2
1| Luigi | Active | 3
2| Peach | Active | 1
2| Peach | Active | 2
2| Peach | Paid   | 3
3| Bowser| Active | 1
3| Bowser| Active | 2
3| Bowser| OFF    | 3
```

I need a query that returns the users and their status in the following hierarchical way:

1. If between the status of the user we have an OFF, we print it.
2. Else, if between the status of the user we have a Paid, we print it.
3. Else, if between the status of the user we have an Active, we print Active.

The output would be something like this.

```
1| Luigi | Active 
2| Peach | Paid 
3| Bowser| OFF
```

I have tried an IFF with some sort of success, but it ignores the Active users.

```
SELECT User_id, Name, Status
FROM tbl_payments
group by User_id, Name
Having Status = IFF( EXISTS( SELECT Status WHERE Status = 'OFF'), 'OFF', 'Paid')
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?  If not, then what is your actual database?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I'm using SQL server, I'm testing your solution :) Thank you so much Tim!

Comment: ...something against Little Goomba `:-/` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Do not let me start with those little guys... haha Thank you again Tim!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your version of SQL support `ROW_NUMBER`, then we can use it along with a `CASE` expression:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User_id
                                 ORDER BY CASE Status WHEN 'OFF'    THEN 1
                                                      WHEN 'Paid'   THEN 2
                                                      WHEN 'Active' THEN 3 END) rn
    FROM tbl_payments
)

SELECT User_id, Name, Status, Payment_No
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

That should work in all databases

```
SELECT User_id, Name, 
       case when max(Status) = 'Active' then 'Active'
            when max(Status) = 'OFF' then 'OFF'
            when max(Status) = 'Paid' then 'Paid'
       end as Status
FROM tbl_payments
group by User_id, Name
```

Comment: This solution omits the payment number column (which admittedly would not be an issue should the OP not require it).

Comment: Can we not simplify the `case` statement here?